# ASP.NET Core File Validation Custom Attributes not being triggered

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I want to validate files on my application using serverside and custom logic using attributes.

i have this model

```
public class FileTest {

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [MaxFileSize(3 * 1024 * 1024)]
        [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".pdf" })]
        public IFormFile File { set; get; }
}
```

here are the custom attributes

```
    public class MaxFileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly int _maxFileSize;
        public MaxFileSizeAttribute(int maxFileSize)
        {
            _maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(    
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var file = value as IFormFile;
            //var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            //var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".png" };`enter code here`
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.Length > _maxFileSize)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public string GetErrorMessage()
        {
            return $"Maximum allowed file size is { _maxFileSize} bytes.";
        }
    }



    public class AllowedExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly string[] _Extensions;
        public AllowedExtensionsAttribute(string[] Extensions)
        {
            _Extensions = Extensions;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var file = value as IFormFile;
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (!(file == null))
            {
                if (!_Extensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public string GetErrorMessage()
        {
            return $"This photo extension is not allowed!";
        }
    }
```

basically, whenever i post the form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input asp-for="FileTest.File" class="form-control" multiple>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Definition.File" class="text-danger"> 
                                    </span>
<button type=""submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

page model

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{

    if(!ModelState.IsValid){
    }

    return Page();

}
```

The file is not invalidated if i upload an excel file for example, it bypasses modelstate. Using debugger it does not trigger the custom validation attributes, it jumps directly to Post Handler

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention this is a razorpage. On my razorpage all I have is this

```
public FileTest File { get; set; }
```

According to @KirkLatin the issue was missing the BindProperty. Validation Attributes are not triggered if this tag is missing. Learned something new!

Comment: what about pdf files?

Comment: You are not passing the model to the method?`public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(FileTest  modal);`

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a razorpage and even if i pass pdf it won't trigger the attributes

Comment: You don't appear to have `[BindProperty]` above your `File` property, so I guess model-binding isn't even running and your `File` is `null` in `OnPostAsync`, right?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks this was the issue... I missed this despite having worked with razorpages for awhile already. It happens i guess

Comment: Yeah, things like that are easily missed.

Comment: @KirkLarkin true but i thought i could trigger the validation attributes code after post but at least now it is known

Comment: `[BindProperty]` marks the property as something that should be populated by model-binding. The validation process is part of model-binding (it comes after), so if there's no model-binding, there's no validation.